# Neo4j and Java: fast and random sample of Iterable<Relationship>

Tags: java, neo4j, guava

I've coded a traversal in Java which returns an Iterable. The **worst case** is an Iterable size of 850784 relationships.

**Objective**: I want to sample (without replacement) only 20 relationships and I want to do it fast.

**Solution 1** : performing a `toList()` or casting it in some sort of `Collection` takes too much time (> 1 minute). I know I could have taken avantage of the `shuffle()` function, etc. but it was unacceptable.

**Solution 2**: thus, in order to do this directly on the `Iterable`, I've used the **guava** `collect` library, I have included the time in milliseconds (calculated with `System.nanoTime()` and dividing by 1000000), for each of the 3 steps below. I need to take the size of the `Iterable` for the random number generator, this is a real bottleneck.

```
    /* TRAVERSAL: 5 ms */
    Iterable<Relationship> simrels = traversal1.traverse(user).relationships();

    /* GET ITERABLE SIZE: 74669 ms */
    int simrelssize = com.google.common.collect.Iterables.size(simrels);

    /* RANDOM SAMPLE OF 20: 28321 ms*/
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    int[] idxs = new int[20];
    Random randomGenerator = new XSRandom(seed);
    for (int i = 0; i < idxs.length; ++i){
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(simrelssize);
        idxs[i]=randomInt;
    }
    Arrays.sort(idxs);

    List<Relationship> simrelslist2 = new ArrayList<Relationship>();
    for(int i = 0; i < idxs.length; ++i){
        if (i > 0) {
            int pos = idxs[i]-idxs[i-1];
            simrelslist2.add(com.google.common.collect.Iterables.get(simrels, pos));
        }
        else{
            simrelslist2.add(com.google.common.collect.Iterables.get(simrels, idxs[i]));
        }
    }
```

**How can I optimize this code to go faster ?**

Note: I have a Windows 8.1 PC, i5 2.30GHz, RAM 16GB, HDD 1TB

As per Michal's request, please find file contents below:

**neo4j-wrapper**

```
#********************************************************************
# Property file references
#********************************************************************

wrapper.java.additional=-Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties
wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties

#********************************************************************
# JVM Parameters
#********************************************************************

wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow

# Remote JMX monitoring, uncomment and adjust the following lines as needed.
# Also make sure to update the jmx.access and jmx.password files with appropriate permission roles and passwords,
# the shipped configuration contains only a read only role called 'monitor' with password 'Neo4j'.
# For more details, see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html
# On Unix based systems the jmx.password file needs to be owned by the user that will run the server,
# and have permissions set to 0600.
# For details on setting these file permissions on Windows see:
#     http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/security-windows.html
#wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3637
#wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true
#wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
#wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=conf/jmx.password
#wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=conf/jmx.access

# Some systems cannot discover host name automatically, and need this line configured:
#wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$THE_NEO4J_SERVER_HOSTNAME

# Uncomment the following lines to enable garbage collection logging
#wrapper.java.additional=-Xloggc:data/log/neo4j-gc.log
#wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCDetails
#wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
#wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
#wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintPromotionFailure
#wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size in MB.
wrapper.java.initmemory=8192
wrapper.java.maxmemory=10240

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper settings
#********************************************************************
# path is relative to the bin dir
wrapper.pidfile=../data/neo4j-server.pid

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=neo4j

# User account to be used for linux installs. Will default to current
# user if not set.
wrapper.user=
```

**neo4j.properties**

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, either in bytes or
# as a percentage of available memory. This will be clipped at the amount of
# free memory observed when the database starts, and automatically be rounded
# down to the nearest whole page. For example, if "500MB" is configured, but
# only 450MB of memory is free when the database starts, then the database will
# map at most 450MB. If "50%" is configured, and the system has a capacity of
# 4GB, then at most 2GB of memory will be mapped, unless the database observes
# that less than 2GB of memory is free when it starts.
#mapped_memory_total_size=50%

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true".
#keep_logical_logs=7 days

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false.
#node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled.
#node_keys_indexable=name,age

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false.
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled.
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age

# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#remote_shell_enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0 for all interfaces).
#remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
#remote_shell_port=1337

# The type of cache to use for nodes and relationships.
#cache_type=hpc

# Maximum size of the heap memory to dedicate to the cached nodes.
#node_cache_size=

# Maximum size of the heap memory to dedicate to the cached relationships.
#relationship_cache_size=

# Enable online backups to be taken from this database.
online_backup_enabled=true

# Port to listen to for incoming backup requests.
online_backup_server=127.0.0.1:6362


# Uncomment and specify these lines for running Neo4j in High Availability mode.
# See the High availability setup tutorial for more details on these settings
# http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M02/ha-setup-tutorial.html

# ha.server_id is the number of each instance in the HA cluster. It should be
# an integer (e.g. 1), and should be unique for each cluster instance.
#ha.server_id=

# ha.initial_hosts is a comma-separated list (without spaces) of the host:port
# where the ha.cluster_server of all instances will be listening. Typically
# this will be the same for all cluster instances.
#ha.initial_hosts=192.168.0.1:5001,192.168.0.2:5001,192.168.0.3:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating cluster status
# information iwth other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
#ha.cluster_server=192.168.0.1:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating transaction
# data with other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
#ha.server=192.168.0.1:6001

# The interval at which slaves will pull updates from the master. Comment out
# the option to disable periodic pulling of updates. Unit is seconds.
ha.pull_interval=10

# Amount of slaves the master will try to push a transaction to upon commit
# (default is 1). The master will optimistically continue and not fail the
# transaction even if it fails to reach the push factor. Setting this to 0 will
# increase write performance when writing through master but could potentially
# lead to branched data (or loss of transaction) if the master goes down.
#ha.tx_push_factor=1

# Strategy the master will use when pushing data to slaves (if the push factor
# is greater than 0). There are two options available "fixed" (default) or
# "round_robin". Fixed will start by pushing to slaves ordered by server id
# (highest first) improving performance since the slaves only have to cache up
# one transaction at a time.
#ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed

# Policy for how to handle branched data.
#branched_data_policy=keep_all

# Clustering timeouts
# Default timeout.
#ha.default_timeout=5s

# How often heartbeat messages should be sent. Defaults to ha.default_timeout.
#ha.heartbeat_interval=5s

# Timeout for heartbeats between cluster members. Should be at least twice that of ha.heartbeat_interval.
#heartbeat_timeout=11s
```

Comment: Can't you get the iterable size from when you create it? Also, can you arbitrarily cut the iterable to its 20 first elements?

Comment: @Olivier: I cannot get the first 20 since the order in the `Iterable` was imposed by the traversal, I cannot change this. For the size there is no method "size()" or alike after `.relationships()` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Neo4j is returning an Iterable is that it executes the traversal whilst you're iterating. In order to sample, I'm afraid you have to "visit" every relationship. Yes, you can skip some, but you still have to iterate through all of them at the end of the day.

We're using "reservoir sampling" algorithm for this, [implemented here](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/graphaware/common/util/ReservoirSampler.java). Not sure it's gonna perform much better though, for the reason described above. That said you should be able to sample 1M relationships in less than 1 second with warm cache. If it's taking longer than that, you may need to tweak the memory settings a bit.

Comment: **OK thanks**, I've run a sample with `Iterable<Relationship> simrels2 = com.graphaware.common.util.IterableUtils.random(simrels, 20);` and got result in 71658 ms, it's good because I do not need to get `Iterable` size information. By the way, do you have a comment with regards to  Olivier's answer above ? THX

Comment: Wow, that's slow. Could you share the contents of your neo4j.properties file and neo4j-wrapper.properties? Regarding Olivier's answer, I'm not sure how that's gonna help. There is no way around seeing all the relationships.

Comment: Thanks Michal, please find files content above

Comment: Are you using Neo4j 2.2.x? Could you try to put something like dbms.pagecache.memory=6g into neo4j.properties, maybe decrease your heap size a little bit, and re-test the sampling? I'd be interested timing of subsequent runs (i.e. not the first run with cold caches)

Comment: I'm using Neo4j release **2.2.0-M02**. Honestly, I cannot find the `dbms.pagecache.memory` parameter in any of the configuration files located in the _conf_ folder ...

Comment: then add it please :) And upgrade to 2.2.2 if you can.

Comment: Thanks Michal, in which configuration file should it be located? can't find it in the (web) user manual. I will indeed upgrade ASAP ...

Comment: neo4j.properties - see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a `Traverser`:

```
Traverser traverser = traversal1.traverse(user);
int size = traverser.metadata().getNumberOfRelationshipsTraversed();
Iterable<Relationship> simrels = traverser.relationships();
```

Now you have your size and you can optimize your random selector.

Comment: Wow, thanks ! didn't know about `Traverser` ... ok I'm getting a NullPointerException on `int size = traverser.metadata().getNumberOfRelationshipsTraversed();`, I will investigate but if you have an idea please don't hesitate

Comment: I'm not very good at debuging with Eclipse, I've added a breakpoint at the corresponding line, I can see the traverser "framework" content, but cannot detect an "out of bound" cause for this `NullPointerException`, **can someone help me ?** This program works fine, I don't have problems with the traversal results ... why I cannot just retreive its size ?

Comment: I have a `Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable) line: not available` with an `arg0` set to NullPointerException (id=89)